# How can i install a xml template on Blogger?

Tags: xml, templates, blogger, blogspot

I want to install a xml Blogger template and i really don't know how....

I found a [tutorial](http://www.premiumbloggertemplates.com/2010/02/how-to-uploadinstall-blogger-template.html) over the internet but meanwhile the Blogger administration panel has changed.

Comment: There is nothing call as **install a xml Blogger template**... You must try it.. Its there on 'Edit html' on your blogger settings page. Give a try buddy...

Answer (score 1):

**m3tsys**, you can still go back to the old Blogger administration panel. I have done the same thing and I can install the xml theme by uploading the xml file. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

1. Go to your Blogger admin
2. you will find template; click it
3. then you can see back/restore; click that button
4. then you can upload your own Blogger XML template.